# How to remove absolute path in android

Tags: android, android-listview, absolute-path

I have a list-view in which i am loading a audio file from server and by clicking on any item it play's that audio. Now i have a problem is that i am getting full path that is absolute path and i just want the name of that file only.

[image]

So basically in above image you can see that it is printing full path with //..../.mp3 and i just want to show file name only. So how can i do this.

I have tried many solution like **.getName()** method with file and string object but it is not working properly.

Below is my code.

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                urlAudio = new URL("http://server/folder/uploadAudio");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();
            List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                tempList = lister1.listAll(urlAudio);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
                myList.add(tempList.get(i).split("/")[tempList.get(i)
                        .split("/").length - 1]);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: use string.split() method

Comment: @user88, where exactly i have to use this string.split?

Comment: can you upload the code of `listAll()` method ?

Comment: @Kedarnath, listAll() is a default method, no need to define explicitly, i have used apache ivy library that take cares of it.

Comment: Who is downvoting, please specify the reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
        ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            tempList = lister1.listAll(urlAudio);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
            myList.add(tempList.get(i).split("/")[tempList.get(i).split("/").length-1]);
        }
```

**Update:** replace your whole `doInBackground()` method body by following code snippet...

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            urlAudio = new URL("http://i-qualtech.com/Fidol/uploadAudio");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            tempList = lister1.listAll(urlAudio);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
            myList.add(tempList.get(i).split("/")[tempList.get(i).split("/").length-1]);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Okay wait moment, i will try and let you know.

Comment: Still the same not getting exact result, it is showing full path only.

Comment: then your problem lies any where else.

Comment: May be, but i don't know exactly what is the problem and where.

Comment: you have tow `AsyncTask`...change both of them.

Comment: But other one is for video and i am not using that right now in my project.

Comment: Then, clean your project and run it. another thing, you should initialize your `myList` in `doInBackground()` method before start to inserting value into the `myList`...thats will be good.

Comment: can you please show me what update have you made in your code from my suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 String filename = urlAudio.toString().substring(
            urlAudio.toString().lastIndexOf("/") + 1, urlAudio.toString().length())
```

Comment: Where should i use this?

Comment: Where you want to display or store filename there you can use this .

Comment: @InnocentKiller use this line where you are adding path in your `List<String> myList`

Comment: It is showing error in lastIndrxof and error is `The method lastIndexOf(String) is undefined for the type URL`. Here urlAudio is declared as URL

Comment: @InnocentKiller make it `urlAudio.toString.lastIndexOf("/")`

Comment: And if i do this then it shows error on substring and error is `The method substring(int, int) is undefined for the type URL`.

Comment: @InnocentKiller: now see my updated answer try it and tell me if any prob

Comment: @BlackTiger, Sorry for this silly question, but i have updated my full activity code, can you tell me where exactly i can use your code.

Comment: @InnocentKiller: I think `ApacheURLLister` and `lister1.listAll(url1);` take only urls so i think i fail to bind my code with it. beacause if we pass only file name then your player code might be stop working..

Comment: Okay, but cant we hide the front part of url and just show the file name to user's actually full path is available but only file name is visible to user's.